# User Activity API client id in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am calling User Activity API using

```
analyticsreporting.userActivity.search({
            requestBody: {
                "viewId": "*******",
                "user": {
                    "type": "CLIENT_ID",
                    "userId": `25336095.1669186824 `
                }
            },
            auth: authClient
        }, function (err, result) {
```

I am migrating to GA4, how do I get this done for GA4?

Comment: You don't there isn't currently a user activity option in the data api.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Do you any date it will start working? Universal analytics will be stopped on 1st July 2023.

Comment: I haven't heard anything that says they are going to support that feature.   Where did you hear about it.

Comment: Here - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en